# ReactRouter is undefined when bundling with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a weird problem that seems related to webpack, but I am not sure. Here is the context, I am creating a front end using **ReactJS**, and I have a **Java** backend, so what I am trying to do is to compile and bundle all the JS using **webpack** with the config below.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: path.join(__dirname, "src/js/index.js")
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "src/main/resources/static/js"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, "src"),
            "node_modules"
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "less-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

And here is the only JS file, with very basic display that is failing :

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactRouter, {Link} from "react-router";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log(React);
    console.log(PropTypes);
    console.log(ReactRouter);
    console.log(Link);
    console.log(document.getElementById("root"));

    ReactDOM.render(<Link to="/">Home</Link>, document.getElementById("root"));
});
```

I've installed all npm required packages, webpack is running without errors, but when I open the page in the browser, there is an error + warning in the console.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Error: Element type is
>   invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
>   class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

I found that it is because `Link` and `ReactRouter` are `undefined`, but I don't understand how it's possible since they are imported and the package is installed.

Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem ?

Comment: There is a backslash in the string for your import call ```import ReactRouter, {Link} from "react-router/";```

Comment: Sorry it was typo, I tried autocompletion to see if the `Link` was exported by the package, but It seems the package do not exports `Link`. I still have the issue without the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the first comment on your post, you might wanna check out which version of React-Router you have. In the newest version, { Link } is a part of the "react-router-dom" package, and you can replace "react-router"'s { Router } with "react-router-dom"'s { BrowserRouter }.

React-Router-Dom is part of the React-Router package you installed (if it's a newer version), so all you need to do is replace React-Router with { BrowserRouter } and "react-router/" with "react-router-dom".

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules), it shows the modules associated with the React-Router "react-router-dom" package, which includes <Link />. If you check out the base "react-router" package and its modules, you'll see <Link /> is no longer a part of it.

Comment: Thank you, I found a guide to migrate to react-router v4 : http://rants.broonix.ca/updated-upgrading-to-react-router-v4-2/